# Genfromtext Issues with umlauts

Tags: python, genfromtxt

I was just working on a program i made for fun and i came across a problem that i was unable to find a solution to.
The code I wrote looked something like this:

```
import numpy as np

data= np.genfromtxt('list.txt', unpack=True, dtype=("U12", "U12"))
print(data)
```

'list.txt' looked something like this:

```
# random random2
foo ßaar
```

When I try to run this code, the following error-message appears:

> UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
>   C:\Users\syhon\Documents\Test\test.py in ()
>        1 import numpy as np
>        2
>   ----> 3 data= np.genfromtxt('list.txt', unpack=True, dtype=("U12", "U12"))
>        4 print(data)
>
> C:\Users\syhon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in >genfromtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, skip_header, skip_footer, >converters, missing_values, filling_values, usecols, names, excludelist, >deletechars, replace_space, autostrip, case_sensitive, defaultfmt, unpack, >usemask, loose, invalid_raise, max_rows)
>     1927                         dtype = np.dtype(ttype)
>     1928             #
>   -> 1929             output = np.array(data, dtype)
>      1930             if usemask:
>      1931                 if dtype.names:
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

However, as soon as I remove the ß, the code works just fine.
Is there a way to keep the umlauts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

putting

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

in the top line seems to solve the Problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you try manually specifying the encoding?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data= np.genfromtxt('list.txt', unpack=True, dtype=("U12", "U12"), encoding='ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "L:\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1708, in genfromtxt
    first_line = _decode_line(next(fhd), encoding)
  File "L:\\lib\encodings\ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xdf in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> data= np.genfromtxt('list.txt', unpack=True, dtype=("U12", "U12"), encoding='bytes')
>>> print(data)
['foo' 'ßaar']
```

Note: for me `bytes` was already the default encoding, so I was initially unable to replicate your error.

EDIT: To clarify, I mean adding the `encoding` keyword argument to the [`np.genfromtxt()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) function call. When I initially ran your code, there was no error. I could only reproduce your error when setting the encoding to `ascii`.

Comment: Both file use UTF-8-encoding (hope that's what you mean).   
If it's important, my Python version is 3.6.1

Comment: I did not specify the encoding in my code. However, when I try to do so, the following error-message appears:"TypeError: genfromtxt() got an unexpectetd keyword argument 'encoding'.